# My mesh would completely break when i move the bones

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature, geometry

I'm quite new to blender as i made this little electronic hand on my own with only 2 days of experience. but the problem is that when I went to rig it to make it animate it just wouldn't work. the armature is made and the mesh is linked correctly but the arm looks like it becomes a liquid when I move any bone.

when the arm is stationary:
[image: Thats when the arm is stationary]

when moved:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried countless stuff to fix it even remodeled the thing a few times and still it just refuses to work. I tried asking on Reddit for this one and someone replied. if you are reading this then thank you so much! but the problem is that as a beginner I didn't understand a thing of what they said.

the comment:
[image]

and I still don't understand. if anyone can help me with this it will be really REALLY appreciated as I'm working on a game that has this arm as one of the main stuff and it was planned for months. the only thing that held me back for 2 weeks was this stupid arm rig.

that's the project file if it would be of any help to you:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u8LabX_Pr_LT9f-Et4TMPopVqMBIEv0N/view?usp=sharing

and thanks to all of you beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is exactly as the comment you pasted in here:

you have "inner geometry". If you delete that, it should work.

To "see" you inner geometry, you can select your outer faces and then press H to hide them:

[image]

then you can see clearly your "inner geometry".

Delete all that inner geometry in both arms, the select your arms in object mode, shift-select the armature and ctrl-p -> with automatic weights and it works.

Comment: doing this really helped the rig be more complete. thank you so much. but now there are some more problems I have no idea how to fix. one fo them is that when I move something like the forearm it wouldn't be connected to the bisep which isn't that big of a deal considering I can just put a sphere in there to make it more natural.

but the biggest problem is the fingers. not the joints themselves they look not perfect but acceptable. the problem is in the beginning of them. yknow where it says like "Index1.L" or smth. when I move those bones the entire palm is twisted. how do i fix that?

Comment: Hi Tock, 1) if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer so that other people also know what the problem was and how it could be fixed. 2) pls do not ask "further" questions in comments because nobody will and can search for questions/answers in comments  3) pls just open a new question with your new problem - you may open as many questions as you like. thx for your understanding

Comment: oh alr. im sorry im just new here and really don't know how these things work.